# How to perform a maven release from Jenkinsfile?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

How can I perform a maven release from the Jenkins file in my program? I used to have a button in Jenkins which did the maven release from me. Now I am working on Jenkins which is operated through a Jenkinsfile and the button isn't there anymore. I was wondering if there is some configuration I could do on Jenkins in order to do the release. My Jenkins file currently looks like this:

```
    stage('Checkout') {
        scmCheckout {
            deleteWorkspace = 'true'
            maven_version = 'maven 3.6'
        }
    }

    stage('Build') {
        javaCompile {
            goals = "clean install"
        }
    }


stage("Release") {
    //I want to do the release here somehow
}
```

Comment: This is too general. What exactly do you want to do? What did you try? Where have you failed?

Comment: Hi @JFMeier, apologies for that. I have just updated a sample of what my Jenkinsfile looks like

Comment: So what is a "release" for you? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to perform a maven release: https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/ please have a look at the following link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you want to use the maven release plugin (would have been good to mention that in the question). You can call it from a Jenkinsfile just like any other Maven phase or goal. So insteal of  `mvn clean install` you can also call `mvn release:prepare releaes:perform` with the appropriate parameters.